# ReadFile/WriteFile crahes

Tags: winapi

Something wrong with next ReadFile/WriteFile code.
I need to use copy file by using this functions (yes, it's better to use CopyFile, but now I need it), but it crashed at read/write loop.
What can be wrong?

> PS C:\Users\user\Documents\SysLab1\dist\Debug\MinGW-Windows> g++ --version
>   g++.exe (x86_64-posix-sjlj-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.8.3

I used next code :

```
#include <windows.h>

#include <iostream>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define BLOCK_SIZE 1024

uint32_t copy_c(char* source, char* destination) {...}

uint32_t copy_api_readwrite(char* source, char* destination) {
    bool result;
    HANDLE input = CreateFile(source, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, 
        OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (input!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        HANDLE output = CreateFile(destination, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
            CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        if(output!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            DWORD readed;
            char block[BLOCK_SIZE];
            while(ReadFile(input, block, BLOCK_SIZE * sizeof(char), &readed, NULL)>0) {
                WriteFile(output, block, readed, NULL, NULL);
            }
            if(GetLastError()==ERROR_HANDLE_EOF) {
                result = true;
            }
            else {
                result = false;
            }
            CloseHandle(output);
        }
        else {
            result = false;
        }
        CloseHandle(input);
    }
    else {
        result = true;
    }

    if(result) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return GetLastError();
    }
    return result;
}

uint32_t copy_api(char* source, char* destination) {...}

#define COPY_READWRITE

#ifdef COPY_C 
#define COPY copy_c
#else
#ifdef COPY_READWRITE
#define COPY copy_api_readwrite
#else
#ifdef COPY_API
#define COPY copy_api
#endif
#endif
#endif

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if(argc<3) {
        std::cout << "Bad command line arguments\n";
        return 1;
    }

    uint32_t result = COPY(argv[1], argv[2]);
    if(result==0) {
        std::cout << "Success\n";
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Error : " << result << "\n";
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the "crash"? Did you get any error messages? Segmentation fault?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747.aspx) of `WriteFile`:

> **lpNumberOfBytesWritten**
>
> This parameter can be NULL only when the lpOverlapped parameter is not NULL.

You are not meeting that requirement. You will have to pass the address of a `DWORD` variable into which the number of bytes written will be stored.

Another mistake is in the test of the return value of `ReadFile`. Instead of testing `ReadFile(...) > 0` you must test `ReadFile(...) != 0`, again as described in the documentation.

You don't check the return value of `WriteFile` which I also would regard as a mistake.

By definition, `sizeof(char) == 1`. It is idiomatic to make use of that.

When dealing with binary data, as you are, again it is idiomatic to use `unsigned char`.

More idiom. Write the assignment of `result` like this:

```
result = (GetLastError() == ERROR_HANDLE_EOF);
```